# Cause ASP .NET OnCheckedChange server event from Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a checkbox with a OnCheckedChanged event. I change whether the checkbox is checked in javascript sometimes. When I change it via javascript this OnCheckedChanged event doesn't fire.

Is there a way when I change the checkbox via javascript to have the OnCheckedChanged event fire?

Thanks

Comment: What code have you attempted to write to solve your problem?

Comment: You need to understand the difference between **server-side** code and **client-side** code.

Comment: Checking a checkbox gets triggered on the client side. uhgg...nvm not going to entertain the comment

Comment: Write now I'm _doPostBack('upgrOrder', 'OnCheckedChanged'); and replicating the code that I would call in the OnCheckChanged code

Comment: When you check the box "manually" the server side event fires because it has AutoPostBack enabled right? So, check my code below, jQuery doesn't trigger a change event unless you tell it to.

Comment: Please post all relevant code in your original post. It's going to be really hard to help you unless we can see how you're handling some things.

Answer (score -1):

Without seeing the JavaScript that changes it, it's hard to be 100% sure, but usually using the `.change()` part of jQuery triggers the change to behave like a user has clicked it.

So:

```
$("#myCheckbox").prop("checked", true).change();
```

Or

```
$("#myCheckbox").prop("checked", true).trigger("change");
```